# How to fetch JSON for particular user or student

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am currently on to my final year project in University.

The university will provide me all the JSON needed for student.

Now, for example, if a student is to log into the app with their registration number and password, then how will I validate the user through JSON and how am I going to fetch the particular user data to show him/her their transcript, *etc.*?

I know how to fetch simple json from the internet.

Can anyone please share some thoughts on it.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to provide far more information if we should answer that question.

Comment: It sounds like this is a question for your university, not SO. If they're going to provide you with access to all the information you need in JSON format, then they should be telling you how to get that information (a web service, presumably).

Comment: Yes, The task is to implement the whole SIC(Student information center) on Android. Then student will be able to check there Attendence, Transcript, lab availability etc..

Now the issues is that I read this article:http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/   It is working great! but how am I going to fetch json on each user basis

Comment: Sorry for confusion..I don't have JSON for the students right now, I was just asking a way that how to fulfill this task.. any example would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server and host it.

> You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for making API Calls.
>
> 1. Open a Login Activity to the Student and ask the student to enter `username` and `password` into the form.
> 2. Convert the data into JSON using GSON CONVERTERS which are a part of Retrofit Library.
> 3. POST the data to you API link.
> 4. After getting the data on your server check the username and password in your database and return the response as details of the Student as JSON Data for the same.

OR (Not Recommended due to lack of Security)

> 1. Add your JSON Data into your Application as HardCoded String.
> 2. Create a class with all the fields from JSON data and convert the String to Class Object by using:
>
>    ```
>    import com.google.gson.Gson;
>    Gson gson = new Gson();
>    String json_string = JSON_DATA_STRING;
>    ClassModel model = gson.fromJson(json_string,ClassModel.class);
>    ```
>
>    If its an array of JSON Objects you can use:
>
>    ```
>    ClassModel[] model = gson.fromJson(json_string,ClassModel[].class);
>    ```
> 3. Now `model` contains all your JSON data as Java Class Object.
> 4. After getting username and password from Student you can search the `model` for this username and password and show the details from
>      the Java Class Object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by making an HTTP request for the data and then parsing the results. I would suggest trying out the Spring Android library to accomplish this: http://www.springsource.org/spring-android

Comment: Thanks! But I have completed this step already from this article:http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/   Actually I don't know that how to fetch JSON on per user-basis